# как пропорционально уменьшить фото?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения

Вопрос: есть изображение, которое открывается:

```
image = Image.open("C:\\pic.jpg")
image = image.resize((1080, 1080), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

все бы ничего, но изображения бывают разные, и порой resize дико искажает фото. как пропорционально уменьшить фото?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new_size = (1080, 1080)
ratio = min(float(new_size[0]) / image.size[0], float(new_size[1]) / image.size[1])
w = int(image.size[0] * ratio)
h = int(image.size[1] * ratio)
resized = image.resize((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы по месту уменьшить картинку, чтобы она была не больше заданного размера, сохраняя пропорции:

```
image.thumbnail((1080, 1080))
```