# Билинейная интерполяция изображения

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, изображения

Нужно реализовать алгоритм билинейной интерполяции для черно-белого изображения. Вроде всё делаю по формулам, но результат получается абсолютно неверным.
По [ссылке на *github*](https://github.com/Impuling/Image-enhancement/blob/InProgress/Bilinear.ipynb) Вы можете увидеть, собственно, результат.

Насколько я понимаю, проблема где-то в цикле (ну, в общем-то, больше и негде ей быть, наверное).

Вот код:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

%matplotlib inline


img = Image.open("5.jpg", 'r')
img = img.convert('L') # преобразование в изображение в оттенках серого

# imshow(np.asarray(img))

im_array = np.asarray(img)
# img.save("5_resize.jpg")

pix = img.load() # выгрузка значений пикселов
height, width = im_array.shape

result_arr = np.empty((500, 500)) # создание нового массива

for x in range(height-1):
    for y in range(width-1):
        result_arr[2*x, 2*y] = pix[x,y]
        result_arr[2*x, 2*y+1] = pix[x,y] * ((2*y+2)-(2*y+1))/((2*y+2)-2*y) 
        + \
                             pix[x+1, y+1] * ((2*y+1)-2*y)/((2*y+2)-2*y)
        result_arr[2*x+1, 2*y] = pix[x,y] * ((2*x+2)-(2*x+1))/((2*x+2)-2*x) 
        + \
                             pix[x+1, y+1] * ((2*x+1)-2*x)/((2*x+2)-2*x)

    for y in range(width-1):
        result_arr[2*x+1, 2*y+1] = result_arr[2*x+1, 2*y] * ((2*y+2)- 
        (2*y+1))/((2*y+2)-2*y) + \
        result_arr[2*x+1, 2*y+2] * ((2*y+1)-2*y)/((2*y+2)-2*y)
        # result_arr[(2*x)+1, (2*y)+0] = (pix[x+1, y] + pix[x,y]) / 2
        # result_arr[(2*x)+0, (2*y)+1] = (pix[x, y+1] + pix[x,y]) / 2
        # result_arr[(2*x)+1, (2*y)+1] = (pix[x+1, y+1] + pix[x+1, y] + 
         pix[x, y+1] + pix[x,y]) / 4
        print(result_arr)

result_img = Image.fromarray(result_arr, mode = 'L')
imshow(np.asarray(result_img)) # преобразованная картинка
# result_img.save("5_resize.jpg")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729228/simple-efficient-bilinear-interpolation-of-images-in-numpy-and-python

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему** или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. "результат получается абсолютно неверным" - это не описание.

Comment: вы хотите увеличить или уменьшить картинку?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, я забыла написать: требуется уменьшение изображения в 2 раза.

Comment: связанный вопрос [как пропорционально уменьшить фото?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/836518/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Модуль PIL уже умеет все это делать из коробки:

```
from PIL import Image

# https://lizzierosswriter.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/3150494-7873411214-5.jpg
img = Image.open("c:/download/5.jpg", 'r')
img = img.convert('L')

factor = 0.5
w, h = img.size
new_w = int(w * factor)
new_h = int(h * factor)

img.resize((new_w,new_h), Image.ANTIALIAS).save('c:/download/res_antialias.jpg')
img.resize((new_w,new_h), Image.BILINEAR).save('c:/download/res_bilinear.jpg')
```

Исходное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

res_antialias.jpg:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

res_bilinear.jpg:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий вариант программы

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.misc import imread, imshow
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def BilinearInterpolation(imArr, pix, posX, posY):

    X_int = int(posX)
    Y_int = int(posY)
    X_float = posX - X_int
    Y_float = posY - Y_int
    X_int_inc = min(X_int+1, imArr.shape[1]-1)
    Y_int_inc = min(Y_int+1, imArr.shape[0]-1)

    bl = pix[Y_int, X_int]
    br = pix[Y_int, X_int_inc]
    tl = pix[Y_int_inc, X_int]
    tr = pix[Y_int_inc, X_int_inc]

    b = X_float*br + (1. - X_float)*bl
    t = X_float*tr + (1. - X_float)*tl
    result = int(Y_float*t + (1. - Y_float)*b + 0.5)

    return result

path = input("Path to picture: ")
img = Image.open(path, 'r')
img = img.convert('L') # преобразование в изображение в оттенках 
                       # серого
imArr = np.asarray(img)
pix = img.load() # выгрузка значений пикселов
k = input("Resize coefficient : ")
k = float(k)
newShape = list(map(int, [imArr.shape[0]*k, imArr.shape[1]*k]))
resultImg = np.empty(newShape, dtype = np.uint8)
rowScale = float(imArr.shape[0]) / float(resultImg.shape[0])
colScale = float(imArr.shape[1]) / float(resultImg.shape[1])

for r in range(resultImg.shape[0]):
    for c in range(resultImg.shape[1]):
        old_r = r * rowScale 
        old_c = c * colScale
        resultImg[c, r] = BilinearInterpolation(imArr, pix, old_c, 
                          old_r)

plt.imshow(np.uint8(resultImg), cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```